# Round up to two decimals in eclipse android

Tags: android, eclipse, decimal

Someone who can help me making this round up to two decimals instead of showing all of the decimals in android?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoSmj.png]

Comment: Convert it to String, then split it upto two decimal places, and then convert it back to Integer or double.

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below. This will give you a string in return with just 2 decimal places.

```
// Continuing from the code you have on thee link ... 
double Udregning = aValue * EuroTilKroner;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
String s = df.format(Udregning);
result.setText(s);
```

Hope this helps else please comment.

**Update**

As @Oren nicely suggested, you may set the rounding mode as follows:

```
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
```

For more modes see the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.format("%.2f", value)`, your double will be rounded automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public static String roundAndFormatDouble(double value,int scale) {
   try {
     BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
     bd = bd.setScale(scale, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
     String roundedValue  = bd.toString();
     return roundedValue;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ""+value;
}
```

Both the rounding and formatting part can be handled with this API.

Please note if you use bd,doubleValue(), you might not get exactly scaled number of decimal place in some  cases.For eg: 50.0.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
//continuing from code
Udregning = aValue * EuroTilKroner;
String abc = String.format("%.2f", Udregning);
result.setText(abc);
```